# Delete first 3 characters and last 3 characters from String PHP

Tags: php, string, character, strip, substr

I need to delete the first 3 letters of a string and the last 3 letters of a string. I know I can use substr() to start at a certain character but if I need to strip both first and last characters i'm not sure if I can actually use this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Pass a negative value as the `length` argument (the 3rd argument) to [`substr()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), like:

```
$result = substr($string, 3, -3);
```

So this:

```
<?php
$string = "Sean Bright";
$string = substr($string, 3, -3);
echo $string;
?>
```

Outputs:

```
n Bri
```

Answer (score 30):

Use

```
substr($var,1,-1)
```

this will always get first and last without having to use strlen.

**Example:**

```
<?php
    $input = ",a,b,d,e,f,";
    $output = substr($input, 1, -1);
    echo $output;
?>
```

***Output:***

a,b,d,e,f

Comment: This is a much more versatile answer than the accepted one, however accepted answer meets the required 3 character problem.

Comment: How is this answer ‘much more versatile’ than the accepted one? Please be specific.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in other answers you can use one of the following functions to reach your goal:

- [substr($string, 3,
  -3)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) removes 3 chars from  start and end
- [trim($string, ",")](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) removes all specific chars from start and end
- [ltrim($string, ".")](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) removes all specific chars from start
- [rtrim($string, ";")](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) removes all specific chars from end

It depends on the amount of chars you need to remove and if the removal needs to be specific. But finally `substr()` answers your question perfectly.

Maybe someone thinks about removing the first/last char through [string dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.const-dereferencing). Forget that, it will not work as `null` is a char as well:

```
<?php
$string = 'Stackoverflow';
var_dump($string);
$string[0] = null;
var_dump($string);
$string[0] = null;
var_dump($string);
echo ord($string[0]) . PHP_EOL;
$string[1] = '';
var_dump($string);
echo ord($string[1]) . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

returns:

```
string(13) "Stackoverflow"
string(13) "tackoverflow"
string(13) "tackoverflow"
0
string(13) "ackoverflow"
0
```

And it is not possible to use `unset($string[0])` for strings:

> **Fatal error**: Cannot unset string offsets in **/usr/www/***.php** on line **

Answer (score 2):

```
substr($string, 3, strlen($string) - 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know php, but can't you take the length of the string, start as position 3 and take length-6 characters using substr?

Comment: Well if I do substr, it doesn't really take out the characters. If I do the substr($var, 3) it will start at the 3rd position. Then if I do the substr($var, -3) it will still have the first 3 characters in the string, and will end 3 characters early. I need it to remove characters entirely.

Comment: it looks like Sean Bright has provided your answer. or did you mean to remove the characters from the original string? i know it's not technically the same thing, but you could replace your original variable with whatever substr returns.

Comment: No Sean Bright and others are right, when i originally commented to this the other answers were not there :S

Answer (score 1):

```
$myString='123456789';
$newString=substr($myString,3,-3);
```