# How can i cut the first 11 characters from a string?

Tags: php, string

How can I cut the first 11 characters from a string, I would like to display some name of some images, but all my images has 11 random characters and a _ before the actual name of the picture shows, I would like to get rid of these 11 characters before displaying the name.

I tried this:

```
substr($foto_filename,0,11)
```

But it does the opposite.

Comment: Have you tried `substr($var, 11, 0)`?

Comment: @D4V1D Yes it displays nothing when I do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete first character and last character from String PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045618/delete-first-character-and-last-character-from-string-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [manual](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
substr($foto_filename, 11);
```

Comment: @Athax Maybe do a lot more research before you ask these kind of questions?

Comment: May be early morning. He obviously read at least something ;) Btw, its possible to accept answer that helped by clicking "check" mark under upvote/downvote arrows.

Comment: @yergo Thanks for the headsup, I checked the answer now.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php $str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
echo $str2 = substr($str,11);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$srt = substr(trim($string), 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

$name = '0123456789A_Image.png';

echo substr ( $name, 0 , 11 );   // 0123456789A

echo substr ( $name, 11 );  // _Image.png

echo substr ( $name, 12 ); //Image.png

[substr() PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$string = "How can i cut the first 11 characters from a string?";
echo substr($string , 11, strlen($string));
```

11 :  indicate start position
strlen($string) :  last position of the string

Reference : [PHP - Substr](http://php.net/substr)

Comment: `strlen($string)-11` to be canonical with manual. Such answer may bring some misunderstoodment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = "thisisasamplestring";
$count = strlen($str);
echo substr($str, (11-$count), ($count-11));
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e8796f9b1dfb2394bbd37e6638dff3fdd4f5e1d

Comment: use it if you want to calculate from end of the string