# Replace first and last digit with * in php

Tags: php, string, substring

I want to replace 1st and last digit of a number series with *. such as I have

```
$number = 123435987345735372;
```

I want to get such as

```
*535738753957353*
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/ref.strings : all you ever wanted to know about php strings.

Comment: Related :- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045618/delete-first-character-and-last-character-from-string-php

Comment: How we get the above expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
$number = 123435987345735372; 
$new_number = substr($number, 1, -1);
$new_number = "*".$new_number."*";
echo"original number: $number<BR>new number: $new_number";
```

Like what Norbert van Nobelen said, check out the manual at php.net

Comment: Thank's Bradon for your kind help.

Comment: `preg_replace('~^.|.$~', '*', $str);`

Comment: Bradon answer is little bit confusing but it was my 1st question and he tried to help me so i appreciate him.......................but your answe is appropriate . tnx bro for your help...........#Avinash Raj