# Unexpected result when getting the first image in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have string :

```
<img style="max-width:100%" src="http://media.doisongphapluat.com/thumb_x670x/2015/12/26/thumon.png" alt="">
```

Trying to get src of this image :

```
<?php 
preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+)[\'"].*>/i', $step6[0], $image);
echo $image['src']; ?>
```

Result :

```
http://media.doisongphapluat.com/thumb_x670x/2015/12/26/thumon.png" alt="
```

Why **" alt="** appear here and how to remove it ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `.+` repetition in the `src` group is greedy. Therefore, it would try to match as many characters as possible, thus extending beyond the bounds of the *src* property.

To fix it, you can simply make the repetition lazy by adding a question mark at the end - `.+?`.

[More on the subject](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

---

So just change your regex to:

```
<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/yG9lA3/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `explode();` on `src=` and then trim off the remaining `=` and the `"` at each end if you don't want them:

```
 <?php
 $string = '<img style="max-width:100%" src="http://media.doisongphapluat.com/thumb_x670x/2015/12/26/thumon.png" alt="">';

 $string = explode("src=", $string);
 $string = explode(" ", $string[1]);
 $string = substr($string[0], 1, -1);  // remove 1st and last "
 echo $string;
 ?>
```

You will need to be sure that your HTML has no single inverted commas and escape them if it does like this `\'`

Last line to remove first and last character borrowed from @SeanBright 's answer here: [Delete first character and last character from String PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045618/delete-first-character-and-last-character-from-string-php)

`$string = explode('src=', $string);`  works - tested. Then you only need to remove the `" "` afterwards with  `$string = substr($string[0], 1, -1);  // remove 1st and last "`.

You could also remove both of the double inverted commas with

```
$string = str_replace('"','',$string);
```

I think your regex is failing because it is just getting everything after the src=" but not stopping at the space. Others have commented elsewhere that regex is not the most reliable way to split up HTML.

If you don't want `explode();` you could split the string using `strpos()` and `substr();`

```
$string = '<img style="max-width:100%" src="http://media.doisongphapluat.com/thumb_x670x/2015/12/26/thumon.png" alt="">';

$pos = strpos($string,'http');
$string = substr($string,$pos, -9);  // remove last " and alt-...
echo  $string;
```

This will only work if the end of the image tag is as yours but would fail if the tag close `/>` was there so you would need to use a bit more code to make that fully programmatic:

```
$string = '<img style="max-width:100%" src="http://media.doisongphapluat.com/thumb_x670x/2015/12/26/thumon.png" alt="">';

$pos = strpos($string,'http');   // find position of !http!
$string = substr($string,$pos);  /// get string after !http"
$len = strlen($string);          // get the length of resulting string
$pos1 = strpos($string,'"');     // find last "
$difpos = $len - $pos1;          // get the difference to use for the minus
$string = substr($string,0,-$difpos);  // get the string from 0 to "minus" position at end.
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<?php
$input = "<img style='max-width:100%' src='http://media.doisongphapluat.com/thumb_x670x/2015/12/26/thumon.png' alt='' />";
$pattern = "/(http.+)'\salt/";
preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
?>
```

It will give :

> http://media.doisongphapluat.com/thumb_x670x/2015/12/26/thumon.png

`$matches[1]` gives the content inside the parenthesis, and `\s` is for the white space before `alt`.