# How to replace certain character in php

Tags: php, str-replace

I need someone who can make the following output which is a single string

```
[{"mobile":"XXX-XXX-XXXX","permaddress":"{\"country\":\"country\",\"state\":\"state\",\"city\":\"city\",\"street\":\"street\"}","tempaddress":"{\"country\":\"country\",\"state\":\"state\",\"city\":\"city\",\"street\":\"street\"}"}]1
```

to

`{"mobile":"XXX-XXX-XXXX",
"permaddress":"{\"country\":\"country\",\"state\":\"state\",\"city\":\"city\",\"street\":\"street\"}",
"tempaddress":"{\"country\":\"country\",\"state\":\"state\",\"city\":\"city\",\"street\":\"street\"}"}`

Help me removing first '[' and last ']1' in the above string. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045618/delete-first-character-and-last-character-from-string-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,

```
<?php
$str = '[{"mobile":"XXX-XXX-XXXX","permaddress":"{\"country\":\"country\",\"state\":\"state\",\"city\":\"city\",\"street\":\"street\"}","tempaddress":"{\"country\":\"country\",\"state\":\"state\",\"city\":\"city\",\"street\":\"street\"}"}]1';
$temp_str = preg_replace('/\[/',"",$str);
$new_str = str_replace("]1","",$temp_str);
echo $new_str;
?>
```

Output,

```
{"mobile":"XXX-XXX-XXXX","permaddress":"{\"country\":\"country\",\"state\":\"state\",\"city\":\"city\",\"street\":\"street\"}","tempaddress":"{\"country\":\"country\",\"state\":\"state\",\"city\":\"city\",\"street\":\"street\"}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
$final_str =  rtrim(ltrim($your_str, '['), ']1');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove first and last character from your string

```
$result = substr($string, 1, -2);
```

Here is the link if you want to explore more:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try [ltrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) and [rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
$str = '[{"mobile":"XXX-XXX-XXXX","permaddress":"{\"country\":\"country\",\"state\":\"state\",\"city\":\"city\",\"street\":\"street\"}","tempaddress":"{\"country\":\"country\",\"state\":\"state\",\"city\":\"city\",\"street\":\"street\"}"}]1';
$getTrim = ltrim($str, '[');
$getTrim =  rtrim($getTrim, ']1');
echo $getTrim;
```

OR

```
$getTrim =  rtrim(ltrim($str, '['), ']1');
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `str_replace` or `preg_replace` replace your keyword with empty string.