# How to remove the quotation marks

Tags: html, css, laravel

```
$title=$movieArray['title'];
echo $title;
```

The value of the string after echo out is **"Sherlock"**. 
How to remove the quotation marks of a string to become **Sherlock**

Comment: jsut use this `substr($title,1,-1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete first character and last character from String PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045618/delete-first-character-and-last-character-from-string-php)

Comment: `echo trim($title, '"');`

Comment: Maybe you should consider stripping it before it goes into the database, stripping it out everytime is inefficient.

Comment: I would first check the reason why you're getting that in the first place, it might indicate that something else has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace() for this.

```
$title = str_replace('"', '', $movieArray['title']);
```

Replaces the "-Quotationmark

Answer (score 0):

```
$title=$movieArray['title'];

$title = trim($title,'"');

echo $title;
```

Comment: Could you provide some additional detail for the OP - why his did not work, etc.  It is a help to new users.