# remove front and last of the character of a string in php

Tags: php, string, substr

My goal is to create a function that removes the first and last characters of a string in php.

**My code**:

```
function remove_char(string $s): string {
    $len = strlen($s);
    return substr($s,1,$len-2);
}
```

This not past the codewar code test. Can anyone tell me why it is not correct?

Comment: Works [**perfectly for me**](https://3v4l.org/VJEBZ). Please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. Note that the explicit `string` type will only be valid in PHP 7 though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete first 3 characters and last 3 characters from String PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045618/delete-first-3-characters-and-last-3-characters-from-string-php)

Comment: Questions without any errors are off-topic on StackOverflow.  Perhaps you would like your working code to be reviewed at CodeReview.

Answer (score 1):

The built in function substr is accepting negative value, when you use negative value it affect readability. You can also give the function name better and clearer name like so:

```
function modify_string(string $s): string {
  return substr($s, 1, -1);
}
```

Comment: If you also want to control the offset at the beginning or at the end: `function modify_string($string, $offset_b = 1, $offset_e = 1) { return substr($s, $offset_b, 0 - $offset_e); }`

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
   function remove_char(string $s){
      if(strlen($s) > 1){
          return substr($s, 1, -1);
      }
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate future readers.  Always endeavor to include some manner of explanation regarding why/how it is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function remove($word){
$result = substr($word, 1, -1);
return $result;
}
$word = 'HELLO';
$results = remove($word);
echo $results;

?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/893528)

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate future readers.  Always endeavor to include some manner of explanation regarding why/how it is the solution.